# prevent user from creating password from his last 4 passwords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on rails in mvc framework and i want to prevent user to create password from last 4 passwords.

here is what i have done so far,actually I was following that code of someone from github but it seems he didn't have mentioned `encrypted_password_changed` function and `encrypted_password` function.

Password Histories Table

```
class CreatePasswordHistories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table(:password_histories) do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string  :encrypted_password
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :password_histories
  end
end
```

User Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  has_many :password_histories
  after_save :store_digest
  validates :password, :unique_password => true

  private

  def store_digest
    if encrypted_password_changed?
      PasswordHistory.create(:user => self, :encrypted_password => encrypted_password)
    end
  end
end
```

Custom Validator

```
require 'bcrypt'
class UniquePasswordValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.password_histories.each do |ph|
      bcrypt = ::BCrypt::Password.new(ph.encrypted_password)
      hashed_value = ::BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret([value, Devise.pepper].join, bcrypt.salt)
      record.errors[attribute] << "has been used previously." and return if hashed_value == ph.encrypted_password
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: anybody can help me out with this?

Comment: What is the actual question? what issues are you running into?

Comment: `encrypted_password` is the column in the `users` table, which automatically gives you the  `encrypted_password` and `encrypted_password_changed?` methods in Rails

Comment: what about the encrypted_password_changed? is it predefined function or something which will give me results? actually when i execute my code it'll say ndefined method encrypted_password_changed? i'm confused that where i should define it?

Comment: @chumakoff will you please explain a little more

Comment: Do you have the `encrypted_password` column in the `users` table?  Rails generates `*_changed? ` method for each column.
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

Comment: @chumakoff i'll send you my schema screenshot please check